# Using external server restlet framework

Tags: java, php, rest, web-hosting, restlet

I am using the Restlet Framework, but now I want to change to a proper server instead of using localhost.
I have already added my php files (they access the java files using the rest_server URL) to the server's folder and my java files as well, but I am not sure how to change the code so it identifies where the new location of the files is.

Here is the code from IdentiscopeServer (constructor empty):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //setsup our security manager
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null){
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    identiscopeServerApp = new IdentiscopeServerApplication();

    IdentiscopeServer server = new IdentiscopeServer();
    server.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP,8888);
    server.getDefaultHost().attach("", identiscopeServerApp);
    server.start();

}
```

I guess that the correct line to change is the one with "Protocol.HTTP, 8888". If the address of my new server is http://devweb2013.co.uk/research/Identiscope, how exactly do I set this up? Is there anything else necessary for it to work apart from just moving the files to a folder in the server?

The IdensticopeServerApplication is the following:

```
public class IdentiscopeServerApplication extends Application {

public IdentiscopeServerApplication() {
}

public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    //attaches the /tweet path to the TweetRest class
    router.attach("/collectionPublic", CollectionPublicREST.class);
    router.attach("/collectionPrivate", CollectionPrivateREST.class);
    router.attach("/analysis", AnalysisREST.class);
    return router;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance, it is my first time using this Framework.

Comment: It is hard to provide help without know much about classes IdentiscopeServerApplication & IdentiscopeServer

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the post, see above.

Comment: I want to see the code of those classes because i believe all the rest service connection logic is there. The code you have provided in your question is from a very abstract layer.

Comment: Any ideas? Just ignore the comment "//attaches the /tweet path to the TweetRest class" on the IdentiscopeServerApplication class

Comment: the restlet code will normally detect the server it is deployed upon the context from the request URLs. How are you looking to deploy the Application? In a Servlet Container? using one of the Restlet engines?

Comment: So far I have only copied the java project to the server (it is not running on the server yet), but I already have the server's address in which it will be running on. However, I am not very familiar with this framework, so I am not sure how to proceed now, or how to set the server's address in the application. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to run your main() method as the server, correct?  In this case, the code for main() needs to be in a location that -- when running -- can provide the service at http://devweb2013.co.uk/research/Identiscope.  Since you haven't stated what kind of server you are putting the code, I can't say where the best place to put the code would be.  I assume you have superuser privileges on your deployment server, since the URL you provided implies port 80 will be serving your Identiscope web service (port 80 is a privileged port on most OS's).  So as an answer, I can only provide general information.

On your deployment server, port 80 must be free (i.e. nothing else should be acting as a web server on port 80 on that machine) and the IdentiscopeApplication must be running on port 80.  To do that, you need only change the line:

```
server.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP,8888);
```

to:

```
server.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 80);
```

then run the application as a user that is allowed to start servers on port 80 (preferably NOT the superuser).  If you haven't already, you will need to get Java running on your deployment server and make sure all Restlet libraries are in the classpath where you plan to run your application.

If I understand what you are trying to do, then this should do the trick.

Comment: Snapman, Thank you very much for your reply. I had some problems with the server lately, but as soon as I test what you proposed, I will post here if it worked out or not. Thanks!